# Can't get text/innerHTML of h1 element in DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to fetch the text of two h1 elements but my methods keep returning "Undefined" when executed. Here's the first h1 element

```
<div id="product-details" class="floatLeft">
  <h1 class="productTitle">Krista Sued Coat</h1>
</div>
```

my code for fetching this content

```
var productName = $('#window').contents().find('h1.productTitle').innerHTML;
```

The second h1 element

```
<div class="product-title-wrap">
  <h1 class="product-title font-alpha">
    <span itemprop="name">



            Bliss Firm, Baby, Firm!


        </span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

my code for fetching this content

```
var brandName = $('#window').contents().find('.product-title font-alpha span').innerHTML;
```

both of these return "Undefined" each time. I've been trying for hours to solve this issue and nothing works. If anyone can provide an answer I'd be really grateful if you could also explain how your method works since I'm still new to jquery and trying to learn a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: [**jQuery's find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) returns a [**jQuery object**](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) containing a collection of pointers to the DOM element(s) not the DOM Element itself. Use `.html()` for jQuery objects and `.innerHTML` for DOM elements.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? If there's a problem please explain so in the comments. I don't want to get banned from asking questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `jQuery` object not `DOM` object. innerHTML is property of DOM object and you are trying to use it with jQuery object.

*Change*

```
var productName = $('#window').contents().find('h1.productTitle').innerHTML;
```

*To*

```
var productName = $('#window').contents().find('h1.productTitle')[0].innerHTML; //With javascript
```

or

```
var productName = $('#window').contents().find('h1.productTitle').html(); //With jQuery
```

Comment: Or just use the `.html()` jQuery method.

Comment: This works for the h1.producTitle element but doesn't work for the .product-title font-alpha span content, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined

Comment: @user2028856: I think `.product-title font-alpha span` should be `.product-title.font-alpha span`

Comment: Try using .product-title.font-alpha instead of .product-title font-alpha

Comment: @Adil, thanks so much this works! But could you please explain why this works though? I always thought you declare classes/id/tags in jquery the same way you do in CSS. So why does chaining the two together with a . get it to work?  Thanks again

Comment: .product-title font-alpha means you are looking for tag name font-alpha within parent having class product-title

Answer (score 5):

You can use html method of jQuery:

```
var productName = $('#window').contents().find('h1.productTitle').html()
```

Comment: what is the main difference between .text() .innerHTML and .html() in this case fetching the text within the tags?  Thanks

Comment: text gives you only text content of element by removing html tags inside. html() and innerHTML gives same result. innerHTML is native, html is method of jQuery.